# Slow MariaDB when Query Joining Million of Records

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I installed a plug in and I have done optimisation on the back end (SSD, single column indexing for columns called in GROUP BY  & WHERE)
but when running this query

```
SELECT  u.user_id, u.profile_page_id, u.server_id AS user_server_id, u.user_name, u.full_name, u.gender, u.user_image, u.is_invisible, u.user_group_id, u.language_id, u.birthday, u.country_iso, m.*
FROM(
(SELECT m.*
FROM phpfox_channel_video AS m
INNER JOIN phpfox_channel_category AS mc
    ON(mc.category_id = mc.category_id)
INNER JOIN phpfox_channel_category_data AS mcd
    ON(mcd.video_id = m.video_id)

WHERE m.in_process = 0 AND m.view_id = 0 AND m.module_id = 'videochannel' AND m.item_id = 0 AND m.privacy IN(0) AND mcd.category_id = 17
GROUP BY m.video_id
ORDER BY m.time_stamp DESC
)) AS m
JOIN phpfox_user AS u
    ON(u.user_id = m.user_id)

ORDER BY m.time_stamp DESC
LIMIT 24;
```

it takes 20 seconds, while changing it to this instead

```
SELECT  u.user_id, u.profile_page_id, u.server_id AS user_server_id, u.user_name, u.full_name, u.gender, u.user_image, u.is_invisible, u.user_group_id, u.language_id, u.birthday, u.country_iso, m.*
FROM(
(SELECT  m.*
FROM phpfox_channel_video AS m
INNER JOIN phpfox_channel_category_data AS mcd
    ON(mcd.video_id = m.video_id AND mcd.category_id = 17)
WHERE m.in_process = 0 AND m.view_id = 0 AND m.module_id = 'videochannel' AND m.item_id = 0 AND m.privacy IN(0) 
GROUP BY m.video_id
ORDER BY m.time_stamp DESC
)) AS m
JOIN phpfox_user AS u
    ON(u.user_id = m.user_id)

ORDER BY m.time_stamp DESC
LIMIT 24;
```

This runs about 5-6 seconds

The phpfox_channel_video contains 2 million rows (and will keep on adding quickly, its a social media site and user can upload files too) so caching isn't quite useful (but activated).

Any hints on how to optimise this ? I have minimum experience with MariaDB/MySQL as I've been accustomed to MS SQL for big data, and creating my own structure. Any recommended method without needing much altering to the tables (adding tables is OK).

Or should I need to restructure the PHP & table to optimise the query to be below 1 second / query.
Thank you!

I found these links
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory & 
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots#indexing

Are they still relevant ?

attached is the explain results [image]
And as for the Index, the current config is set to index every column is stated as an index key, all all the tables involved in the query above.

Would a print out of my current server configuration be helpful ? Thanks !

Comment: Add teh EXPLAIN od your queries and which indexes you have or a create table for all tables involved-

Comment: hi @nbk I've updated the post. Any feedback ?

Comment: The first two links that you provide is by @RickJames

Comment: @tcadidot9 Thanks, i will message him

Comment: Yes, those two links are still valid.  I do update them "as needed".  (There relevance is another issue.)

Comment: The second link specifically says "Index merge intersection" is perhaps always not as good as a composite index."  That shows up in your `EXPLAIN`.  And it fights against your comment here of "index every column".  (I provide a _composite_ index in my Answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to clean up the query, after checking the table, turns out that

```
WHERE m.in_process = 0
  AND m.view_id = 0
  AND m.module_id = 'videochannel'
  AND m.item_id = 0
  AND m.privacy IN(0)
```

Doesn't need to be run, because all the table matches that condition .. (for the current case of this website).. So I just optimize those long queries. And Manage to hit < 1 second now ..

Answer (score 0):

```
INNER JOIN  phpfox_channel_category AS mc ON(mc.category_id = mc.category_id)
```

Is *almost* useless.

- You don't use any columns of `mc` for other purposes.
- This `JOIN` is performed.
- This `JOIN` verified that there is a corresponding row in `mc`.
- This `JOIN` will bloat the temp table if there are *multiple* corresponding rows.
- Bloat leads to wasted work in the `GROUP BY`.

Similarly, your second query does not use `mcd`.

Please use different aliases for derived tables.  It is hard to follow the multiple uses of `m.`.

This is totally useless:

```
ORDER BY  m.time_stamp DESC
```

MySQL/MariaDB is free to ignore an `ORDER BY` in a derived table.  A table is defined to be an *unordered* set of rows.  Ordering can only be done at the end.

Suggested index

```
m: INDEX(item_id, module_id, view_id, in_process, -- any order; tested with '='
         privacy,   -- sometimes has a list?
         video_id)  -- last
mcd:  INDEX(category_id, video_id)  -- in either order
```

There is a more logical way to do this, and possibly faster:

```
    INNER JOIN  phpfox_channel_category_data AS mcd
          ON  mcd.video_id = m.video_id
         AND  mcd.category_id = 17
```

Remove that, and remove the `GROUP BY m.id`, then add this to the `WHERE`:

```
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM phpfox_channel_category_data AS mcd
               WHERE  mcd.video_id = m.video_id
                 AND  mcd.category_id = 17 )
```

(The index mentioned above still applies.)

Not that I have perhaps eliminated two "filesorts" -- for the `GROUP BY` and the `ORDER BY`.  Another note:  `EXPLAIN` does not always show how many filesorts thre really are.  (But `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` does.)